# Unable to view the environment variable in the sh file when passing it through docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker file

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.45-jdk8-adoptopenjdk-hotspot

RUN mkdir -p /opt/main

WORKDIR /opt/main

COPY run.sh test.sh runmain.sh /opt/main

RUN chmod +x /opt/main/run.sh && bash /opt/main/run.sh

ENTRYPOINT bash /usr/local/tomcat/bin/runmain.sh && /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

An env file

```
ENV_MQ_DETAILS=tcp://10.222.12.12:61616
ENV_DB_HOST=10.222.12.12
```

runmain.sh file has the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${ENV_MQ_DETAILS}
echo ${ENV_DB_HOST}
```

when I run the docker run command

```
docker run --env-file .env bootstrap -d
```

The docker logs shows both env variable values printed.

when I use the docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
    bootstrap:
        image: bootstrap
        container_name: bootstrap
        hostname: bootstrap
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

and run the command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-bootstrap.yaml --env-file .env bootstrap -d
```

I get two issues

1. While running the docker-compose-bootstrap.yaml the environment variables aren't shown in the logs hence can use them in the latest part of the code, why is it so and please help to resolve this (highest priority).

2 In both the cases (docker run and docker-compose run) , it keeps echoing the files in /opt/main/ folder
but nothing to bother though, but why ?

Please help in resolving the above issues.

Comment: why you dont try to give env files with `-env_file` section inside your docker-compose?.

Comment: @N0ll_Boy , you are a macho man.... it worked like hot knife through a butter.... Any hint on the second part of the question

Comment: i dont know what you mean about second part. since you set `WORKDIR` and and `COPY` files to `/opt/main/` every time you start docker since they are layer's on top of origin image then when you are going to use built image every layer of that image should execute since it has workdir and copy layer. so it will always copy file to  `/opt/main/`.